# Getting data from a long function to update a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, queue

I've got a GUI which gives the user the option to run a selection of tests.

These tests run in threads as they use MIDI data in.

I have a `checkQueue()` function that is run using `after()` but once the user selects a test, the `checkQueue()` function is no longer called until the function finishes.

How do I get the checkQueue to continue running during my `buttonTest()` function so I can use data from the test to update the GUI?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Queue

class Program(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

        self.q = Queue.Queue()

        self.after(200, checkQueue, self.q, self)

    def initUI(self):
        start = tk.Button(self.parent, command=self.runTest, text="Run Test 1")
        start.pack()

        self.instruction = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Press Button 1")
        self.instruction.pack()

    def runTest(self):
        buttonTest(self)

def checkQueue(q,app):
    print "Calling checkQueue"
    while not q.empty():
        #HandleData (update a label/canvas etc.)
        app.update()
    app.after(200, checkQueue,q,app)

def buttonTest(gui):
    #Does lots of functions but is just a while for this example
    x=1
    while x==1:
        if x == 100:
            gui.q.put("Some Data")



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background="black")
    app = Program(root)

    root.mainloop()
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `buttonTest` is the function that's calling your tests that are running in other threads. Even though the actual work is done in child threads, `buttonTest` is still running in the main thread, and its `while` loop is hogging all the main thread's processing cycles. Try starting `buttonTest` itself in its own thread. This will give the main thread the breathing room necessary to process your `checkQueue` calls.

```
def runTest(self):
    Thread(target=buttonTest, args=(self,)).start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin, how would I feed arguments into `buttonTest()` if I were to use this method? As `buttonTest()` isn't part of the gui class, it's part of a separate module in my actual code.

Comment: You can supply arguments using the `args` named argument. Erase `self,` from the second line of the above code and stick in whatever arguments you want to feed in.